# Segmentation fault when creating linked list with function

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a linked list and then echo the node values to the console. But using a function outside the `main` function and calling it is causing `segmentation fault(core dumped)`. I can't figure it out why.
The following code works :

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node* next;
};

void printList(node* start)
{
    node* temp; 
    temp = start;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The value in the "<<i<<"th node is : "<<temp->val<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
}
int main() 
{
    node* start;
    node* temp;
    start = new node;
    temp = start;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp->val = i*10;
        temp->next = new node;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->val = 0;
    temp->next = NULL;
    printList(start);
    return 0;
}
```

But this throws a segmentation fault

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node* next;
};
void createList(node* start)
{
    node* temp;
    start = new node;
    temp = start;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp->val = i*10;
        temp->next = new node;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->val = 0;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
void printList(node* start)
{
    node* temp; 
    temp = start;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The value in the "<<i<<"th node is : "<<temp->val<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
}
int main() 
{
    node* start;
    createList(start);
    printList(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A simple debugging session would have revealed to you that "start" has not changed value after calling createList. Then you would have had asked a more focused question such as "why doesn't start change value when createList returns?"

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I will do it from next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `start` parameter into the function `createList` by value, which means that when you do

```
start = new node;
```

the *copy* of `start` is being assigned the address of the new node. This means that the `start` variable that you declare in `main` does not receive the address of the node.

To fix this, use a pointer reference. Pass `start` to `createList` by reference, instead of by value. Like this:

```
void createList(node*& start)
```

When you pass-by-reference, you're changing the pointer you declared in main directly, rather than creating a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Change `void createList(node* start)` to `void createList(node*& start)`. ([See it work](http://ideone.com/11b7lA)).

In C++, unless specified otherwise, everything is passed by value. In this case, you're passing a pointer to a node (`start`) to `createList` *by value*. You can alter the node it points to (`start->...`), but not the pointer itself, as you're working with a copy.

Passing the pointer by reference allows you to change the pointer itself.